# how many different ways a set of ten variables could be ranked from highest to lowest value, given three possible integer values for each variable

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm trying to solve a problem involving how many different ways a set of ten variables could be ranked from highest to lowest value, given three possible integer values for each variable.

It's been too long since I worked with permutations and combinations, so I would appreciate any guidance on how to go about working through a problem like this.

I started out being given three possible integer values for each variable:

- A: 172, 86, 129
- B: 156, 79, 117
- C: 80, 40, 60
- D: 60, 30, 45
- E: 56, 29, 42
- F: 52, 27, 39
- G: 48, 25, 36
- H: 24, 12, 18
- I: 16, 8, 12
- J: 12, 6, 9

Assuming each of these variables could randomly have any of the three listed values, any tips on how to go from here to a number of the possible ways this list of variables can be ranked from highest to lowest?

My instinct was to look for tiers of where each variable could fall in the list, and I compiled the possible of ranking possibilities for each variable (where each variable could possibly fall in a list ranked from highest to lowest values) - but I wasn't sure where to go from here:

- A: 1, 2
- B: 1, 2, 3
- C: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
- D: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
- E: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
- F: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
- G: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
- H: 8, 9, 10
- I: 8, 9, 10
- J: 8, 9, 10

  Thanks for your help!